# Determine the next number in the sequence

Tags: gr.group-theory, algorithms

This problem originates from a [programming interview problem](http://www.ardendertat.com/2011/10/18/programming-interview-questions-9-convert-array/). In that problem, we are asked to convert the array $[a_0, a_1, \cdots, a_{N-1}, b_0, b_1, \cdots, b_{N-1}, c_0, c_1, \cdots, c_{N-1}]$ into $[a_0, b_0, c_0, \cdots, a_{N-1}, b_{N-1}, c_{N-1}]$ in place. We can verify that the number originally at index $i$ would be moved to the new index
$$
f(i) = 3(i \mod N)+[i/N], \qquad 0\leq i \leq 3N-1.
$$
It also seems that if we repeatedly apply $f$ to the same index $i$, eventually there will be an integer $n$ such that $f^n(i)=i$.

My idea was that we repeatedly move the element at index $i$ to the index $f(i)$, and the element at the index $f(i)$ to the index $f^2(i)$ etc. Since these indices form a loop, eventually we'll move all the elements in the set $f^k(i)$ to their correct final positions.

When I program this idea, however, I need to find out **the next element that has not been moved into its correct final position**. For example, in the case N=1001, the next elements (x), the cyclic length, and the sum of the elements in the set $f^k(x)$ are the following:

```
x= 0, len= 1, sum= 0
x= 1, len= 234, sum= 351234
x= 2, len= 234, sum= 351234
x= 4, len= 234, sum= 351234
x= 5, len= 234, sum= 351234
x= 7, len= 234, sum= 351234
x= 10, len= 234, sum= 351234
x= 11, len= 234, sum= 351234
x= 14, len= 234, sum= 351234
x= 19, len= 78, sum= 117078
x= 20, len= 234, sum= 351234
x= 22, len= 234, sum= 351234
x= 35, len= 234, sum= 351234
x= 38, len= 78, sum= 117078
x= 61, len= 234, sum= 351234
x= 79, len= 18, sum= 27018
x= 158, len= 18, sum= 27018
x= 1501, len= 1, sum= 1501
x= 3002, len= 1, sum= 3002
```

What I'm interested to know, is for any positive interger $N$, to find a way to get the next "x" in the sequence in $O(1)$ time and $O(1)$ space. Thanks!

Comment: The following article considers the more general case of permuting a rectangular array in place.  Your problem is the special case of this where the matrix has three rows.  From this I suspect that there is no known answer to your question, only very good approximations.

Fred G. Gustavson, Tadeusz Swirszcz, In-Place Transposition of Rectangular Matrices, *Applied Parallel Computing. State of the Art in Scientific Computing*. Lecture Notes in Computer Science, 2007, Springer Berlin / Heidelberg, full text available at http://www.springerlink.com/content/9755264224612x75/

Comment: Could you add the [algorithms] tag?

Comment: That paper seems very relevant. Thank you very much.

Comment: This is not efficient at all, but why don't you cyclically rotate the last $3N-1$ elements of the sequence until $b_0$ comes into place, then rotate the last $3N-2$ elements until $c_0$ comes into place, and so on. Since the cyclic order of the remaining elements is never disturbed, you always know exactly where things are...

Comment: Does this question have mathematical research interest? Would it fit better on a programming website?

Comment: It could be a math research problem, because those cyclic sets are the orbits of the cyclic group $\{f^k\}$ acting on the set $\{0\leq i \leq 3N-1\}$, and we are trying to identify the smallest elements (the x's above) of those orbits. 

Comment: @Dorais: You are right, that works too. However, it's a $O(N^2)$ algorithm. In the paper mentioned by Ambrus, there is a $O(N log(N)$ algorithm, where $N=mn$ for a $m\times n$ rectangular matrix.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: yes, because this is an algorithms question, not a programming question.  


Comment: @Gerry Myerson It is definitively a research question, with a stream of related research articles.
